# Need help with a trigger test

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, salesforce-id, master-detail

I am extremely new to salesforce and am having trouble working on a project for work. I need to test my trigger for adding a discounted quote to an opportunity based off of the original quote amount. Here is my trigger and my trigger test code.

```
trigger AddDiscountTrigger on Opportunities__c (before insert) {

   Opportunities__c[] opp = Trigger.new;

   AddDiscount.applyDiscount(opp);
}
```

Here is my updated Trigger using sfdcfox's feedback .

```
 @isTest 
private class AddDiscountTestClass {
    static testMethod void validateAddDiscount() {
       Accounts__c  a = Accounts__c  (Name = 'test'); // add more fields, if required
       insert a;
       Opportunities__c o = new Opportunities__c(Name__c=a.Id , quote__c=100);
       System.debug('Price before inserting new book: ' + o.quote__c);

       // Insert Opportunity
       insert o;

       // Retrieve the new Opportunity
       o = [SELECT Discounted_Quote__c FROM Opportunities__c WHERE ID = : o.ID];
       System.debug('Price after trigger fired: ' + o.Discounted_Quote__c);

       // Test that the trigger correctly updated the price
       System.assertEquals(90, o.Discounted_Quote__c);
    }
}
```

I have tested it manually and it works, however I can't get the test to run and give the code the proper test coverage. I keep getting the error System.StringException: Invalid id: test . I am assuming this is because Opportunities are child to my Accounts object in a master-detail relationship but regardless of what I enter it keeps telling me it is an Invalid ID. I could really use some help and would greatly appreciate it. I am sure it is probably something simple I am just not experienced with yet. The main field on this object is also an Auto Number. I am not sure if that will matter or not either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Name__c is what you called your account lookup...

```
@isTest 
private class AddDiscountTestClass {
    static testMethod void validateAddDiscount() {
       Accounts__c a = new Accounts__c(Name='test'); // add more fields, if required
       insert a;
       Opportunities__c o = new Opportunities__c(Name__c=a.Id , quote__c=100);
       System.debug('Price before inserting new book: ' + o.quote__c);

       // Insert Opportunity
       insert o;

       // Retrieve the new Opportunity
       o = [SELECT Discounted_Quote__c FROM Opportunities__c WHERE ID = : o.ID];
       System.debug('Price after trigger fired: ' + o.Discounted_Quote__c);

       // Test that the trigger correctly updated the price
       System.assertEquals(90, o.Discounted_Quote__c);
    }
}
```

Edit: Updated to reflect custom object, per comments.

Comment: Thanks for the help. After I did that I am now receiving the error "System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Account Name: id value of incorrect type: 0013600000KiX50AAF: [Name__c]". Also, I am still not experienced yet but I believe this is a master-detail record with Name__c referring to the child version of Account Name in my Accounts object. Not sure if this makes a difference or not.

Comment: For Name__c tje Data Type is Master-Detail(Accounts). Is this what you are talking about when you say to change it to the specific type?

Comment: Alright, I see what you mean. You are correct, I am changing it to 
Accounts__c  a = Accounts__c  ( = 'test'); // add more fields, if required
but now it won't let me save it with a compile error of "Variable does not exist: Name" 
In my Account__c object I have the standard field with a Field lable of "Account Name" and the Field Name as "Name" in a Text data type. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I updated the question so you can see the full code snippet if you want. It is not letting me save it with the compile error mentioned above.

Comment: @Jack You forgot the keyword "new", so it thinks you're trying to call a function. Since lvalues can be assigned while they're being used as rvalues, the compiler is expecting a variable named Name. I've updated my code snippet for you. Make sure you copy it carefully.

Comment: You are amazing sfdcfox! Thank you, I appreciate all of your help. You were right, I must have accidentally left out the new keyword while making the account. I added it and it worked like a charm, Thanks again and have a great day!